# How to split a string by white spaces in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a list of medicaments with each line containing its commercial name, INN, dose and form etc.

```
00148ASPEGIC                                           ACETYLSALICYLATE DE LYSINE                        900                           MG                  B/6                  O                                  0   071 OOO 05703A00497         P                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
00149SPRIDOL                                           ACETYLSALICYLATE DE LYSINE                        900                           MG                  B/6                  O                                  0   004 OOO 19303A00499         G                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
00150SPRIDOL                                           ACETYLSALICYLATE DE LYSINE                        900MG                         MG                  B/1                  O                                  0   004 OOO 19303A00499         G                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
00151ASPEGIC                                           ACETYLSALCICYLATE DE LYSINE                       1                             G                   B/6 AMP              O                                  0   071 OO  05703A02398         P                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
00152ASPEGIC                                           ACETYLSALICYLATE DE LYSINE                        250MG                         MG                  B/20 SACHETS         O19072003                      11760   047 OOO 25503A0240302102008 P                    10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
00153ASPEGIC                                           ACETYLSALICYLATE DE LYSINE                        500MG                         MG                  B/20                 O                               6680   047 OOO 05703A02597         P213                 10
```

I need to retrieve data only from the first five columns like the following:

```
ASPEGIC | ACETYLSALCICYLATE DE LYSINE | 1G | B/6 AMP
```

The code I'm using to split so far is

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("medic.txt"))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() > 0)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            var pts = line.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Array.ForEach(pts, Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's your issue?

Comment: Don't use Split().  You need SubString() and Trim().  Or use [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-fixed-width-text-files).

Comment: Hans is right, in your example spaces are used for aligning the "columns" but can also be part of the data entry. Therefore you need to define the column positions and use `SubString()` on that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is awfull advice, what if the columns are almost completly or completly filled with characters.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is fixed width columns so use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FIX_WIDTH fixWidth = new FIX_WIDTH(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class FIX_WIDTH
    {
        int[] Start_Position = { 0, 55, 105, 135, 155, 176, 207, 215, 219, 223, 243, 264};
        string[] Column_Names = { "Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C", "Col_D", "Col_E", "Col_F", "Col_G", "Col_H", "Col_I", "Col_J", "Col_K", "Col_L" };
        public DataTable dt;
        public FIX_WIDTH(string filename)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (string col in Column_Names)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
            }

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    List<string> row = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < Start_Position.Length; i++ )
                    {
                        int pos = Start_Position[i];
                        if (pos >= line.Length)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i == Start_Position.Length - 1)
                            {
                                row.Add(line.Substring(pos).Trim());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int length = Start_Position[i + 1] - pos;
                                if (pos + length <= line.Length)
                                {
                                    row.Add(line.Substring(pos, length).Trim());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    row.Add(line.Substring(pos).Trim());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
                
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```