# Regex split OSX df -h output in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I'm parsing some mac OSX log files, and have come across the output of the `df -h` command, which I now need to split.  The line looks like:

```
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
```

Now I can't just split on the `space` character, as there's a space in
`Mounted on`, but I need to split this into the nine fields.

I've tried using `\s{2,}` to split only on multiple spaces, but then there are single spaces between the `Avail` and `Capacity` fields, so I'm bit lost as to how to handle this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like fixed-width csv data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365466/split-a-string-into-sub-strings-by-fixed-width

Comment: There is no search thing a "fixed width CSV".  It is either Fixed width or CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Mounted can be `on` and `off` right?

you can use it like:

```
((Mounted .+?)|.+?)(\s+|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/PS16xo/2)

You may also just split it with space `\s+` and you already know that the word after `Mounted` belongs to it.

Comment: No 'Mounted on' is just a string that contains the mount point on the system.  Thanks though

Comment: @Tony check my edited answer. if the word mounted is the once causing problem. it should solve it

Comment: Thanks, the \s+ seems to have done the job.